# How to get list of all user CA certificates installed in an Android Device?

Tags: android, adb

Need to get a list of all the user CA certificates installed on the device. We can get System certs by running

`adb shell cat /system/etc/security/cacerts/* | grep Issuer:`

Is there a similar way to get user certs as well. If it is not possible, can we alteast open the Activity which shows the install CA certs in the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity which shows user added certificates is `com.android.settings.TRUSTED_CREDENTIALS_USER`.

The certificates are stored in the `/data/misc/keychain/cacerts-added` folder

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Secutity->Trusted credentials. Go to the 'User' tab to see CAs installed by the user.

Comment: That is OK. But I need to populate them from command line preferably using adb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve CA certificates in an Android app without ADB it can be done like this.

This is some example (Kotlin) code to list all user-installed CA certificates on an Android device.
If you change **"user"** to **"system"** you'll get all pre-installed CA certificates:

```
val userInstalledCaCertificates: List<X509Certificate> = try {
  val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
  keyStore.load(null, null)
  val aliasList = keyStore.aliases().toList().filter { it.startsWith("user") }
  aliasList.map { keyStore.getCertificate(it) as X509Certificate }
} catch (e: Exception) {
  emptyList()
}
```