# Using adb to list certificates in Android devices

Tags: certificate, android

I want to use adb to list all certificates installed by USER.

How can I do that?

Comment: Even though this is for a "Security problem", this question is not about security.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35128517/1778421

Comment: I want to list user cert when the device is not rooted

Answer (score 0):

```
shell~$ adb pull /system/etc/security/cacerts.bks`
shell~$ keytool -keystore cacerts.bks -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -storepass changeit -v -list
```

Comment: This only show system cert. But I want "user cert". I known user certs are storage in /data/misc/keychain/ but if device is not rooted adb cannot access it